# Postfix Relay access denied in centos

Tags: centos, email, postfix

I have install postfix in centos 6.4 server and made changes in main.cf file like this.

```
nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
myhostname = server.kavirajan.com
mydomain = kavirajan.com

myorigin = $mydomain  ##line no 99 - uncomment
inet_interfaces = all  ##line no 116 - change to all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain  ##line no 164 - add $domain at the end
mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8  ##line no 264 - uncomment and add your network range
home_mailbox = Maildir/  ##line no 419 - uncomment
```

After I restarted postix and try to connect telnet and send test mail using this.

```
telnet localhost smtp
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 server.kavirajan.com ESMTP Postfix
ehlo localhost
250-server.kavirajan.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from:<user1>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:<user1>
554 5.7.1 <user1>: Relay access denied
```

**Repeteadly I am getting Relay access denied Error.**

THe maillog says:

```
Jun 5 17:53:23 kavirajan postfix/smtpd[28483]: connect from localhost[::1] 
Jun 5 17:53:53 kavirajan postfix/smtpd[28483]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[::1]: 554 5.7.1 <user1@kavirajan.com>: Relay access denied; from=<user1@kavirajan.com$ 
Jun 5 17:53:59 kavirajan postfix/smtpd[28483]: disconnect from localhost[::1
```

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your MAIL FROM: and RCPT TO: you only wrote the username. Try it with the entire mailaddress, i.e. user1@kavirajan.com.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: What do your mailserver logs say?

Comment: I am getting this error

Jun  5 17:53:23 kavirajan postfix/smtpd[28483]: connect from localhost[::1]
Jun  5 17:53:53 kavirajan postfix/smtpd[28483]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[::1]: 554 5.7.1 <user1@kavirajan.com>: Relay access denied; from=<user1@kavirajan.com$
Jun  5 17:53:59 kavirajan postfix/smtpd[28483]: disconnect from localhost[::1]

Comment: I will add that to the question so that it becomes readable.